# How do I take only specified required columns from CSV file and add into a table in postgresql?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Consider I have

```
*----*------*-----------*----------*----------*---------------*----------------*
| id | name | addressid | address1 | address2 | attendancekey | attendancedate |
*----*------*-----------*----------*----------*---------------*----------------*
```

columns in CSV file and I want only

1. **id, name** to be imported in **student** table and
2. **addressid, address1, address2** to be imported in **address** table and
3. **attendancekey and attendancedate** to be imported in **attendance** table in database.

What query to be used to import the required columns into the table?

> Database Postgresql Version - 12
>
> Python Version - 3.4.4
>
> Psycopg2 Version - 2.7.5

Comment: Can you show us the part of your code that causes problems?

Comment: Queries target tables, not files. How are you trying to import the data? That's the code you need to modify and only include the fields you want

Answer (score 0):

You will first have to `COPY` the data to a (perhaps `UNLOGGED`) staging table and populate the tables from there.

Alternatively, you can define a [file_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/file-fdw.html) foreign table on the CSV file (which has to be located on the database server machine) and use that to fill the tables. This would save you temporarily loading the file into the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sequentially... 
1. First create three csv file from main csv file.
a. For `student` table, column will `id` and `name` ;
b. For `address` table, column will `addressid` and `address1` ;
c. For `attendance` table, column will `attendancekey` and `attendancedate`;

Then Execute the below query 
a. `copy student(id,name) from 'filelocation studentfilename.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV;` 
b. `copy address(addressid,address1) from 'filelocation addressfilename.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV;`
c. `copy attendance(attendancekey ,attendancedate) from 'filelocation attendancefilename.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV;`

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the csv using `df.iterrows()` and for each row you can insert into the table just the key you need.